# JavaFX2.2 TableView:How to make a table cell be edited without mouse click?

Tags: javafx-2

I've encounter a problem with editable table cells. I'm using the TableView in my project just as the [Tutorial on Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm).

According to it, I use the setCellFactory method to reimplement the table cell as a text field with the help of the TextFieldTableCell class. However, I found the steps is a little complex to get to the point where the cell can be edited:

1. Let the table cell be selected by using direction key.
2. Press “Enter” to converts the cell to a text filed so that it is ready to be edited.
3. Clicking in the text field allows the contents to be edited

The problem is step 3, that you must use the mouse to click before you can input data in this table cell.

So, is there a solution to avoid step 3? That is the text field allows the data inputting when you just press “Enter”(step 2).

By the way, English is not my native language. Hope I have made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

The [Node can be focused manually](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus%28%29). The `TextFieldTableCell` is a `TableCell` that has a Node (Graphic) `TextField` which will be rendered when the cell is in editing mode. You need to focus to this textField manually but by using `TextFieldTableCell` you cannot access to the textField. However if you would prefer the alternative way described in the tutorial you are referring, then you have a chance to focus. The only changed method from that tutorial is:

```
@Override
public void startEdit() {
    super.startEdit();
    createTextField();
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(textField);
    textField.selectAll();
    // Set the focus
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textField.requestFocus();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start editing in a TableView without mouse-click event, invoke TreeView.edit(rowIndex, tableColumn);

For example:

```
//create tableview object
TableView<YourModel> tableView = new TableView<>();
//create column
TableColumn<YourModel, String> column = new TableColumn<>("Property Name");
//add column to tableview
tableView.getColumns().add(column);
//... your cell factory and the rest
//add an item
tableView.getItems().add(new YourModel());
//if you want to edit the selected item, get its index
int selectedIndex = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
//fire edit
tableView.edit(selectedIndex, column);
```